# Firebug displays incorrect line numbers

Tags: css, firebug

I edited some files (CSS and PHP) on a website. Now Firebug (2.0.9) displays the same line number for every CSS rule within the *Style* side panel. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Firebug - no luck.

Even on this website, every rule I inspect says `(line 1)`.

Anyone knows how I can get Firebug to display the correct line numbers again?

Comment: Probably a silly question but the css wasn't minified (white space removed)?

Comment: Yeah, most likely minified (like here) meaning that it *is* all on one line. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say the changes were to the files, not to Firebug, I would say the issue is the CSS file and Firebug is reporting the line number correctly. That is to say there is no new lines in the file - all rules are on a single line.

Take a look at the .css file in a basic text editor and make sure the white space hasn't been removed. If it has, you may still see the text wrap and look to be on separate lines but this is just how the editor is showing it - word wrap can usually be turned on/off in editors.

If it looks like a big block of text then your CSS has been minified most likely.

Comment: The source of the CSS file can also be checked within Firebug's *Net* panel. Just expand the related request and switch to the *Response* tab. If you don't see any line breaks there, then the output is in a single line. Also note that some CMS like WordPress and frameworks allow to minify the CSS before sending it to the browser.

Comment: OMG - I guess the moral of the story is - If you are still tinkering with your site - Don't minimize CSS! That is exactly what the problem was. I had CSS/JS/HTML MIN via my CDN. Turned it off and viola! Thank you all. Made my life much easier now!

Comment: Feel free to mark as answer. 
Next - take a look at some tools to unminify your CSS